# No such host error in Jenkins pipeline when pushing docker image to unauthorized private registry

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to push a docker image to a private registry without any authentication configured. Below are how the jenkinsfile stages look like.

Without the writeFile command in the deploy stage I get no such host error

```
docker push <private-vm-name>:5000/temp/prototype-be:v1
The push refers to repository [<private-vm-name>:5000/temp/prototype-be]
Get https://<private-vm-name>:5000/v2/: dial tcp: lookup <private-vm-name> on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
```

With the writeFile command I get an AccessDenied exception

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /etc/docker
```

Could someone guide me on how could these errors be resolved in order to push to a private docker registry?

Thanks.

Jenkinsfile stages

```
        stage('Building docker image') {
            steps{
                script {
                    dockerImage = docker.build registry + ":v1"
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Pushing docker image') {
            steps{
                script {
                    writeFile file:"/etc/docker/daemon.json", text: "{
                            "insecure-registries": [
                               "<private-vm-name>:5000"
                            ]
                      }"
                    docker.withRegistry( 'http://<private-vm-name>:5000') {
                        dockerImage.push()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to provide docker registry authentication to the docker plugin in a jenkins pipeline?

Comment: No. My private docker registry does not have authentication configured which is fine. I need to push the docker image to this private registry in my jenkins pipeline. While doing so I am facing challenges - two of which are listed above. Jenkins is running as a docker container and as far as I know it spawns a new docker container for every pipeline it executes.
I have verified that the docker registry is accessible on port 5000 by executing the GET /v2/_catalog api through the curl command from another vm.
My jenkins server and the private docker registry are running on the same vm machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I executed the jenkins-server `dind` docker image with `--insecure-registries` flag. Since the docker container spawned by jenkins was now aware of the private docker registry, the above docker push command worked. Note I also changed the jenkins push command to use the server's ip address instead of the host-name so that I don't need to edit /etc/hosts.